# the Phrasal Verbs ''RUN INTO'' + SB is used in english?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I've been checking out a lot time some lists of  Phrasal Verbs and I've found this : **run into**

[run into](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-into-sb)

[run into another website](http://www.languageforlife.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Complete-PV-list.pdf)

'I've checked out this phrasal verbs and I've been asking myself if this is common used in english mainly in the USA.

According to these website that I've found they say its meaning is:

> to meet someone you know when you are not expecting to:

or

> Meet by accident.

my example are:

- I ran into john at the party
- we've run into them in the last meeting

what do you think ? is it useful this phrasal verb

Comment: Why do you not believe the definitions provided? I'm not sure what you intend your second sentence to mean, but the first is perfectly natural (except that _John_ should have a capital letter!).  If I said that I had 'run into' an acquaintance, my father used to ask facetiously "Did you hurt her?"

Comment: Yes, it is quite common, the thing you might say to a spouse during dinner. "Guess who I ran into today?"